# PostgreSQL identifier cross-check returns different results for qualitatively-identical query

Tags: postgresql

Setup: PostgreSQL 9.3.5

I have two tables with a common identifier (`propid`) that is unique in one table (`property`) and not unique in the second table (`addressstring`). There are no NULL `propid` in either table [UPDATE: not true, there were NULL in `property.propid`], and datatype is INTEGER in both tables.

The following queries - which I assert are functionally identical - return different results:

Query 1:

```
select distinct propid
  from addressstring
 where propid not in (select distinct propid 
                        from property);
-- returns zero rows
```

whereas

Query 2:

```
select distinct propid from addressstring
except 
select distinct propid from property;
-- returns 1478 rows, all non-NULL
```

The problem persisted after VACUUM ANALYZE (I did that just in case, although the tables have not been altered since import, except for the creation of a GIST index on a geometry column in `property`).

When I feed Query 2 as a CTE and look for the 1478 identified `propid` in the `property` table, sure enough they ain't there -

```
select propid 
  from property
 where propid in
              (select distinct propid from addressstring
               except 
               select distinct propid from property);
-- returns zero rows
```

That's as expected, but frankly I can't trust that result given that Query 1 returns zero rows when it should return 1478.

Three part question:

1. am I wrong in assuming that the two queries are functionally
   identical?
2. If I'm not wrong, is there any sensible, defensible explanation for the discrepancy?

And finally

3. do I have to re-write every `select ... where ... not in (select...)` in the `EXCEPT` structure just to be safe?

That last one, if 'Y', is a gigantic PITA given that `select... EXCEPT ... select` is not the 'usual' way that most folks get 'A not in B', because often the `NOT IN` clause is a subset of the set of variables in the primary `SELECT` - e.g.,

```
 SELECT a.objectid AS addressoid, 
        a.propid, 
        b.objectid AS propertyoid
   FROM address a
   JOIN property b ON a.propid=b.propid
  WHERE b.propid NOT IN (SELECT propid 
                          WHERE [some condition]);
```

And yes, the `WHERE` clause could be written as `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 [etc])`, but the discrepancy in results is a BIG problem given that the query using `NOT IN` took a third of a second and the query structure is canonical by the definition in TFD (it is a 'condition that evaluates to a boolean').

Bear in mind - this is not an efficiency issue in the sense that one formulation takes longer than another, valid formulation. This is the fact that **two formulations that are set-theoretically identical, produce very different result sets**.

UPDATE: the Query Plans produced by EXPLAIN ANALYZE are as follows -

Query 1.

```
HashAggregate  (cost=21999.81..22497.30 rows=49749 width=4) (actual time=256.699..256.699 rows=0 loops=1)"
  ->  Seq Scan on nclm_addressstring_2015  (cost=11521.03..21738.10 rows=104683 width=4) (actual time=256.646..256.646 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))"
        Rows Removed by Filter: 209366 -- <-- Removed 100% of rows... WHY?????????
        SubPlan 1
          ->  HashAggregate  (cost=9427.01..11102.22 rows=167521 width=4) (actual time=91.192..123.690 rows=166742 loops=1)
                ->  Seq Scan on nclm_property_2015  (cost=0.00..9008.21 rows=167521 width=4) (actual time=0.006..40.914 rows=167521 loops=1)
Total runtime: 261.303 ms
```

Query 2

```
HashSetOp Except  (cost=10217.08..25651.99 rows=99497 width=4) (actual time=334.126..336.933 rows=1478 loops=1)
  ->  Append  (cost=10217.08..24984.45 rows=267018 width=4) (actual time=133.840..282.611 rows=334668 loops=1)
        ->  Subquery Scan on *SELECT* 1  (cost=10217.08..12207.01 rows=99497 width=4) (actual time=133.840..174.463 rows=167926 loops=1)
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=10217.08..11212.05 rows=99497 width=4) (actual time=133.838..166.212 rows=167926 loops=1)
                    ->  Seq Scan on nclm_addressstring_2015  (cost=0.00..9693.66 rows=209366 width=4) (actual time=0.013..78.953 rows=209366 loops=1)
        ->  Subquery Scan on *SELECT* 2  (cost=9427.01..12777.43 rows=167521 width=4) (actual time=59.971..100.664 rows=166742 loops=1)
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=9427.01..11102.22 rows=167521 width=4) (actual time=59.969..92.796 rows=166742 loops=1)
                    ->  Seq Scan on nclm_property_2015  (cost=0.00..9008.21 rows=167521 width=4) (actual time=0.005..26.279 rows=167521 loops=1)
Total runtime: 343.926 ms
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `distinct` inside the sub-selects (and in "Query 2") is useless and I think Postgres is not smart enough to remove it

Answer (score 2):

In your 1st query there's a NULL returned by the subquery and you're a victim of [Three-valued-logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#Application_in_SQL).

See also:
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/

A simple workaround is to add `WHERE propid IS NOT NULL`. But better switch to `NOT EXISTS` instead, which treats UNKNOWN as FALSE (i.e. Two-valued-logic):

```
select distinct propid
  from addressstring AS addr
 where NOT EXISTS
  (
    select * 
    from property AS prop
    where addr.propid = prop.propid
  );
```

Btw, `property.propid` sounds like the Primary Key and a PK must be defined as NOT NULL :)

Comment: D'oh on the NULLs (my offsider - whose ears will get reddened when he arrives today - assured me that he'd removed all NULL propid property rows). Still... should the return of a single (distinct) NULL compromise the fact that all the elements in the set (say) A = {1,2,3} are unambiguously in the set B = {NULL, 3,1,2}, and thus that none of them are *not* in the set? It would make five billion times more sense if PostgreSQL threw an error any time the subquery results in a `NOT IN` clause included a NULL - rather than returning (**wrongly**) an empty set. A trap even for old players...

Comment: `property` is imported with a different non-null PK (`objectid`) - in future I will make sure to run a query for NULL `propid` rather than trust the word of data-prep underlings: the existence of NULL values for `propid` indicates that rows with `propertytype`=5 exist in the table... and they shouldn't by the time it gets to me. Today is going to be a direly boring day - I am going to have to add null-checks to dozens of other queries, and re-run them.

Comment: @GT no it would not make sense to raise an error, not in a SQL DBMS. This behaviour complies with SQL standard and that's what all SQL DBMS will return. It might make sense in a product/language that does not allow Nulls.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ having thought about it when in less of a homicidal rage at underlings, I agree. It's a semantic issue as to what 'NULL' means, and what `value`<> NULL evaluates to: it evaluates to 'NULL' (which I still find odd). NULL doesn't mean 'No Value' (and I am not silly enough to think it equals `0` or `''`). But the way it works *operationally* seems to mean *Dunno, I give up*. I'm going to look at what the standard uses to justify claiming that an empty value is *not* not equal to a non-empty value. Null-checks must abound because 'nothing' is *not not equal to* 'something' - odd.

Comment: Yes, `value1 <> NULL` evaluates to `UNKNOWN`. Basically it means, is value1 not equal to a value we know nothing about? The answer is "we don't know". It may be equal, it may not. The trick is that `WHERE` keeps only the rows that we are dead sure the answer is "yes"  (condition is TRUE) and rejects any FALSE or UNKNOWN.

Comment: Short rule: never use `IN` and `NOT IN` when the values can be nullable.